# Why does Oracle seem to add extra decimal places when converting number using to_char?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a large Oracle table (millions of rows) with two columns of type NUMBER. I am trying to write a query to get the max number of decimal places on pl_pred (I expect this to be around 7 or 8). When I do a to_char on the column, there are extra decimal values showing up and it says the max is 18 when I'm only seeing around 4-7 when selecting on that column. Anyone know why as well as how to accurately assess what the max amount of decimal places is? I need to transfer this data to SQL Server and was trying to come up with the right precision and scale values for the numeric data type.

```
select 
    pl.pl_pred as pred_number,
    to_char(pl_pred) as pred_char,
    length(to_char(pl_pred)) as pred_len 
 from pollution pl 
 where length(to_char(pl_pred)) > 15
```

Results:

```
PRED_NUMBER PRED_CHAR               PRED_LEN
4.6328      "4.6327999999999987"    18   
5.8767      "5.8766999999999996"    18  
11.19625    "11.196250000000001"    18  
13.566375   "13.566374999999997"    18
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE RHT.POLLUTION
(
  LOCATION_GROUP     VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  PL_DATE  DATE,
  PL_PRED  NUMBER,
  PL_SE    NUMBER
)
```

Update (again): I ran the same query in SQL Developer and got this, where the two values are showing up exactly the same. So that's interesting. I went back and was able to look at the raw data and it does not match up, though. 4.63278 and 5.8767 is what I see. There are some longer ones, like 10.4820321428571. It's like it's treating Number like float but I thought Number in Oracle was exact.

```
"PRED_NUMBER"   "PRED_CHAR" "PRED_LEN"  
4.6327999999999987  "4.6327999999999987"    18  
5.8766999999999996  "5.8766999999999996"    18  
10.4820321428571    "10.4820321428571"      15

Raw data:
4.6328
5.8767
10.4820321428571
```

Comment: can you show a fiddle where this happens, first i thought fractals, but https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=386179078fa0f5ebcbcaf6043c2118b8 shows none

Comment: @nbk will try but I don't have the exact insert statements or raw data (at the moment at least). The table was loaded from an r script that pulls files down and does some processing before writing it to the database. I looked at what you did in the fiddle and not sure if I'd do anything different. Starting to wonder if it's a Toad thing

Comment: can't reproduce what if you run the select statement from sqlplus?  It looks like a rounding problem where it is converting to floating point.

Comment: I ran it in SQL Developer (as opposed to Toad), had that installed as well and got different results! I pasted them in above. I am going to check on the raw data loading this table but yeah, it seems to be an issue with floating point numbers. I am familiar with issues in SQL Server using the float data type, wonder if it is similar here.

Comment: I've seen some oddness with editors. Perhaps just rely on the current database settings as confirmed with: [SELECT data_type, data_length, data_precision, data_scale FROM all_tab_columns WHERE upper(table_name) = 'POLLUTION' and upper(column_name) = 'PL_PRED';]

Comment: Thanks @Isolated. Checked there and it says 22 bytes for length (just using them max I guess?) and nothing in precision or scale columns for any of the Number columns I checked. However, looks like we're using float in SQL Server, which is also recommended by Microsoft when you look up conversion charts. Not sure we really need this level of precision anyway, going to see about rounding it to less decimal places

Comment: @Kelly - it looks like Toad is just apply its own default formatting to numbers. In SQL\*Plus and SQL Developer you could so `show numformat` and `show numwidth`, but  don't know about Toad.

Comment: storing numbers as float is not a good idea.  You see why.

Comment: It's not stored as a float, it's type Number. But we did not set any precision

Comment: If you do not specify the precision or scale, it will be the maximum range and precision.

Comment: The values look as if the "correct" data should be numbers with at most 7-8 decimals, as you stated; but they weren't numeric literals, they were the results of some non-trivial computations, and rounding errors and such creeped in. These "slightly off" results were stored in the db; you don't see them because some setting says to **display** values with at most 7-8 decimal places, in which case your values are rounded first - that is what you saw in your first attempt. The correct "fix" would have been to round the original calculation to, say, 10 decimal places (to leave some wiggle room).

Comment: Before transferring the values elsewhere, or using them in additional computations, you could first execute an update that would perform this rounding in place, after the fact. First make sure this is in fact what has happened. If it is, it's a simple (but possibly time consuming) `update tbl set col = round(col, 10);`. Fixing the data as high upstream as possible is almost always the best solution.

Comment: Did you try this : substr(pl_pred ,INSTR(pl_pred ,'.')+1,length(pl_pred )-INSTR(pl_pred ,'.')) as  pl_pred

Comment: @mathguy- I updated my post to show the raw data- I jumped the gun on that. It appears a value like 4.6328 will be stored as 4.6327999999999987 maybe. When I query it in Toad, it returns to me 4.6328 and when I convert it with to_char, then I get all the decimals. In SQL Developer, I see 4.6327999999999987 when querying on it or converting it. So it's either stored with extra decimal places or something in the query is adjusting it as it pulls it out. So confused. I am going to ask the guy who's giving me this data if I can round to a certain number of decimal places as I load it in.

Comment: @Sund'er - That is helpful to get what is right of the decimal place except I can't figure out if that's the one I should be going with since that will return the extra decimal places, 6327999999999987 instead of 6328.